# Can I use Vue-I18n without a build step?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

If I use Vue2 with *no build step*, is there a way to use Vue-I18n the same way?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-i18n@8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vueApp"></div>

<script>
    const VueI18n = window.VueI18n;
    if (VueI18n) {
        const i18n = new VueI18n({
            locale: 'en',
            messages: {
                en: {
                    hello: 'Hello there!',
                }
            }
        });
        Vue.use(i18n);
    }
    new Vue({
        template: '<div><p>This is Vue!</p><p>{{welcome}} and {{hello}}</p></div>',
        el: document.querySelector('#vueApp'),
        data: function() {
            return {
                welcome: 'Welcome',
                hello: this.$t('hello'),
            };
        },
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope to see

```
This is Vue!

Welcome and Hello there!
```

Instead, the dev console has the message

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_t')
    at Vue.$t (vue-i18n@8:242:19)
    at Vue.data (vuei18.html:29:29)
    at Vue.mergedInstanceDataFn (vue.js:1240:22)
    at getData (vue.js:4758:19)
    at initData (vue.js:4715:9)
    at initState (vue.js:4654:7)
    at Vue._init (vue.js:5014:7)
    at new Vue (vue.js:5092:10)
    at vuei18.html:23:5
```

Am I completely out of luck, or is there a way to make this happen?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`this.$t()` is the same as [`t()`](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/api/#t-key-locale-values) from the `VueI18n` instance (i.e., the result of `new VueI18n()`), so you can use it here:

```js
const VueI18n = window.VueI18n;
let i18n = null
if (VueI18n) {
     
    i18n = new VueI18n({⋯});
    Vue.use(i18n);
}
new Vue({
    ⋮
    data: function() {
        return {
            welcome: 'Welcome',
                    
            hello: i18n?.t('hello'),
        };
    },
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-i18n@8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vueApp"></div>

<script>
    const VueI18n = window.VueI18n;
    let i18n = null
    if (VueI18n) {
       i18n = new VueI18n({
            locale: 'en',
            messages: {
                en: {
                    hello: 'Hello there!',
                }
            }
        });
        Vue.use(i18n);
    }
    new Vue({
        template: `<div><p>This is Vue!</p><p>{{welcome}} and {{hello}}</p></div>`,
        el: document.querySelector('#vueApp'),
        data: function() {
            return {
                welcome: 'Welcome',
                hello: i18n?.t('hello'),
            };
        },
    });
</script>
</body>
```